# GCP VM - Secondary nic lost it's internal IP address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

I've added a second nic, in order to connect to another VPC network.

I've read this https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces
...setup routing, firewall.

Everything was working good, but after some hours, the second nic lost its Internal IP address.

Tried `service networking restart` `ifdown` `ifup` but no luck.

Does anyone have any ideas about what could have happened?

Or how can I prevent this to happen?

Comment: by "private" do you mean internal IP? Or was it external? if it was external and you did not reserved, this ip will be gone after any kind of stop/restart/live migration

Comment: This could be a DHCP issue, but there are not details in your question about the type of addresses that you are using. Install Stackdriver on your instance and review the logs. You will see the DHCP exchange messages.

Comment: @grimmjow_sms yes, internal IP, sorry.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes indeed. it was a DHCP issue. Since in one of my tests I applied `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`, it seems that dhclient couldn't update that file and that made the DHCP lease fail. I'll answer my own question in case this is useful for someone.

Comment: Your answer might be correct but for the wrong reason. I posted a comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question in case it is useful for someone...

On my tests, I did `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` to keep the `/etc/resolv.conf` file static, and by doing that, the **dhclient** script failed to update the file which made the DHCP renew fail.

Bottom line, do not do `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` on multi-nic VMs on GCP since it would end up with a failing DHCP lease.

Comment: Do NOT modify `/etc/resolv.conf`. This file is overwritten by Google every hour when DHCP leases expire. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#resolv.conf

Answer (score 0):

This situation is a limiting one since you can't add more interfaces or remove them "You cannot add network interfaces to, or remove them from, an existing VM." According to the text you quote, I suggest you recreate the instance, in case you have sensitive information in it, 
The option is to create a snapshot and then mount it on the new instance.

[limitations](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces)
[VM instances with multi-interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces)
[Snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots)
[Instance creation from a Snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I solved the issue by re-creating the instance. Fortunately, that is an automated process we have and no data is actually stored on the instance so it was straightforward.